# FileUpload works well locally but not well as I publish the project

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I've developed a web app using asp.net c#. There is a FileUpload Control that must upload personnel photos. But as I published the website, it is not working properly! While on the local version no problem seen. I've been trying the following:

1. Check HttpRuntime in the web.config => executionTime="60", maxRequestLength="4097151"
2. Searching on the web and nothing came out

Here is my code:

```
fupImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"\UploadedImages\" + fupImage.FileName));
fupImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"\UploadedImages\" + fupImage.FileName));
```

What might be wrong with that?

Comment: Does IIS have access to save files on the UploadedImages folder?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set form enctype="multipart/form-data" and path where you are saving does exist and you have permission.  you can check it by debugging..

Here is complete code

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" action="/home/save" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedImages"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");        
    }
```

Comment: there's no MVC tag in the question